# Facebook Messenger: no notification when offline on Android

Tags: facebook, notifications

Steps to reproduce:

1. I go offline (turn off Wi-Fi, turn off 3G)
2. My friend sends me a message through Facebook Messenger.
3. I go online.

Expected result: I receive a notification about the message.

Actual result: There's no notification at all.

Extra info: If I'm online when my friend sends me a message, I do receive a notification.

So, how to receive a notification about messages sent when offline?

Answer (score 0):

Update the app. If doesn't work, update the phone. If doesn't work, switch off and on your phone. If still doesn't work, uninstall and reinstall the app.